# No write permission to SQL database tables from IIS application, despite having application pool setup in SSMS with correct permissions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, permissions, iis-7.5, application-pool

I have a .NET application developed in Visual Studio 2017 deployed to an IIS (version 7.5) server that is now receiving the below error after I published to production, after a year of working just fine:

**The UPDATE permission was denied on the object '[table name]', database '[database name]', schema 'dbo'.**

The only change made to the application was updating an HTML link in an .aspx page.

In IIS I have created a custom application pool with the following settings:

```
Name: Safety App Pool
.NET Framework: v4.0
Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated
Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity
```

In SQL Server, I have setup a security login for IIS APPPOOL\Safety App Pool, and I have added this to the users of the database, and explicitly granted permissions on the database to this user to Connect, Delete, Execute, Insert, Select, and Update.  Remember, this setup worked fine just one week ago.  I published last Wednesday before going on annual leave for a few days (of course), and come back to find people are unable to make updates or inserts from the website.

What is really strange is that even if I change the application pool to a different one that is still currently working and able to update/insert to the same database, I still get the error that this specific application cannot.  This is why I think there is some setting in either the web.config file, or something that Visual Studio did specifically during publishing that is causing the problem. However, I made no changes to any of the configuration/publishing files before pushing to production last week. I have copied and pasted the error as it shows up in the Application Event Log:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/18/2018 10:24:43 AM 
Event time (UTC): 7/18/2018 3:24:43 PM 
Event ID: 81f28c8d624b48f2a02c489663556877 
Event sequence: 42 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Safety-2-131764005145890618 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Safety 
    Application Path: D:\wwwroot\Safety\ 
    Machine name: IGSKIACWVMGS011 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6600 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Safety App Pool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'SHA_Site_Servicing', database 'simsdb', schema 'dbo'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicUpdate(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at Safety.SHAEdit.ibHazard_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) in D:\gitrepos\sims\Safety\SHAEdit.aspx.cs:line 482
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://sims.water.usgs.gov/Safety/SHAEdit.aspx?site_id=3000336 
    Request path: /Safety/SHAEdit.aspx 
    User host address: 136.177.160.25 
    User: GS\dterry 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Safety App Pool 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 57 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Safety App Pool 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicUpdate(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at Safety.SHAEdit.ibHazard_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) in D:\gitrepos\sims\Safety\SHAEdit.aspx.cs:line 482
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: what is the connectionstring for that db? Is it configured for Integrated Security?

Comment: It is. Data Source=IGSKIACWVMGS011;Initial Catalog=simsdb;Integrated Security=True

Comment: @DeannaTerry Have you checked that update working for any other database table?

Comment: What is your IIS Identity, is the user has the permission to access the MS SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

or

```
Integrated Security=True;
```

from your connection string.

Comment: Why will this help? Do you need to add something else to the connection string?

Comment: I got a very similar error message, despite having all permissions. When I deleted that from connection string, it worked. You can also remove `Integrated Security=True;` too.